# How does electrical charge on a reflective plate affect the reflection of an electromagnetic wave off the plate?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, charge

An electromagnetic wave propagates in air toward a reflective plate and reflects off the plate. Is there any difference in the wave's reflection if the plate is charged versus uncharged?

Related: an electromagnetic wave propagates through a medium. Is there any difference in the propagation or any change in the wave if an electric field (either static or changing) is applied in the medium through which the wave propagates?

Answer (score 0):

Electromagnetic wave propagation happens because:

1. a rapid change in magnetic field causes a changing electric field
2. a rapid change in an electric field causes a changing magnetic field
3. the process repeats

A constant electric or magnetic field doesn't affect this process. It's the *change* of the electric field vs time that generates the constant magnetic field, not the absolute value of the electric field. I.e. a static electric field doesn't generate a magnetic field. So a constant electric field in the vicinity doesn't affect anything. (Obviously, it could affect things by physically twisting the mirror or otherwise changing the properties of the mirror's molecules).

Comment: What decides where electric field and magnetic field will get released?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "released". Also that sounds like it should probably be a new question.

Comment: Can you personally(chat) tell me this if you know.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about vacuum and a perfect reflector, then the answer is no. In this case, Maxwell's equations are linear. The solution with the static charge/field only and the solution describing the wave can be superposed (with no "interaction") to yield the actual solution.

This is not always the case, specifically in the presence of nonlinear media. Static charges/fields can change the properties of media in which waves propagate, thus affecting the waves themselves. Consider a semiconductor as an example. You can induce charge carriers (electrons or holes) in the semiconductor by placing static charges nearby, much like how dopants influence the equilibrium carrier concentration in a semiconductor. An increased carrier concentration can increase the absorption of radiation by the semiconductor: this is called free carrier absorption.